# How would I go about implementing auto-hide on a custom task pane?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I'm creating an Outlook 2007 add-in using Visual Studio 2008 and C#.

I have my custom task pane along with my usercontrol docked to the bottom of the main Outlook window.  I'm trying to implement auto-hide on this taskpane so that it minimizes to a certain size when the mouse leaves it.  My problem arises in the fact that custom task panes have very very few events, namely, `DockChanged` and `VisibilityChanged`.  Nothing about gaining or losing focus, or mouse entering and exiting.

Another problem is that the mouse entering/exiting my pane doesn't fire events on my usercontrol.  I'm assuming that this is because my user control has a flash control which fills my usercontrol.  My workaround was to use the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events from the flash control.  This works decently EXCEPT for the fact that if the user resizes the task pane the `LostFocus` event fires which causes the task pane to hide - yet still be resizing.

So...how would I go about implementing an auto-hide pane in Outlook 2007 using C# around these restrictions?

Comment: Tumbleweed Badge...there's one I hoped never to get.  But I guess that means my question has stumped most?  Or simply slipped through the cracks?  Poorly stated?

Comment: Deeper Outlook-AddIn-Knowledge is just not that common - you get somewhat better responses in microsoft.public.office.developer.com.add_ins

Comment: did microsoft.public.office.developer.com.add_ins have anything mcAden? I'd say you have to subclass the usercontrol and add interop calls to trap mouse/keyboard hook events. With those you can guarantee the event will fire. Although it will still be tough I guess to keep track of the bounds of the taskpane itself.

Comment: A lot of things have changed in my UI and I might be able to get it to work by now but at this point my client has pretty much accepted that it's not going to happen so I'm not too worried about it.